# Kv file cannot include file in subdirectory

Tags: python, kivy, include, python-3.6, kivy-language

On my mission to repack my Kivy project in a more MVC style I decided to create a Views folder for all my widgets that has a large method set for my App. I created a `main.kv` and `main.py` file that will act as my controllers.  Within my Views folder I created a `home.py` and `home.kv` file.   But I found that I could not `#:include` the `home.kv` file in my `main.kv` file from a subdirectory.  I read on a git issue comment thingy [#1341](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/1341) that it is not possible.  The thingy is older than my shoes, so I ask again here.
The .py home file :

```
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

class Home(FloatLayout):
    pass
```

The .kv home file :

```
#: import FloatLayout kivy.uix.floatlayout

<Home>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.73,0.73,0.73,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    ScreenManager:
        id: _screen_manager
        Screen:
            name: 'home'
            ActionBar:
                pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 0.99}
                size_hint_x: 0.98
                canvas:
                    Color:
                        rgba: (0,0.4,0.51,1)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size
                ActionView:
                    use_separator: True
                    ActionPrevious:
                        title: "Tuis"
                        with_previous: False
                        app_icon: ''
                        color: (1,1,1,1)
```

In the main.kv file I incude the home class with `#: include views.home.kv`.
It throws a `FileNotFound` error.  Of course I decided to place the  home files in the same directory which worked.  But is it possible to `include` a .kv file from a subdirectory and what is the syntax?

Comment: Try changing `#: include views.home.kv` to `#: include views/home.kv`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Logical solution and correct answer as always.  Cannot believe I did not think of it.  Thank you.  If you make your comment the answer I will mark it as the solution.  I am using Kivy v1.11.1.